# Randomly strange behaviour when using select() with timeout on Windows

Tags: c#, c++, sockets

I'm using a tool to communicate with a gameserver. To establish the connection with the gameserver I'm sending a login packet and then go on from there. I also used a tool, that does the same, but which is written by someone else in C# with a pre-made library. This app has some issues with stackoverflow exceptions after using it for hours and porting it linux isn't much fun aswell, therefore I decided to write my own application from scratch in C++.

My script pretty much looks like this:

```
while (!connected) {
     if (connectCounter == 0)
        std::cout << "Trying to connect..." << std::flush;
    else
        std::cout << "." << std::flush; // add point

    connectCounter++;

    int selectSize = 0;
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(mysocket, &fds);

    selectSize = select(mysocket + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &timeout);
    if (selectSize == 1) {
        // we might now be logged in, check routines
        connected = true;
     }
}
```

Now there's a "bug" randomly happening to me in both applications, the one written by someone else in C# and in my own one. I should probably mention that I've never had this behaviour before, but sinced I formatted my computer I saw this issue happpening for the first time.

Issue: Gameserver was offline for some hours, computer was probably freshly booted. Gameserver is still down and I start the application. Now it tries to login but won't have success as the gameserver is still offline. Now it writes "Trying to connect". Because of the timeout settings it should wait 5 seconds and then add 1 point after every unsuccessful try. Instead it fires point after point without waiting for the timeout. This happens in both application, the C# app written by someone else and in my own application. In both applications it only happens randomly and not every time I'm starting the application. As I mentioned I've never experienced this issues before formatting my computer. I also ported this application to my linux server and didn't not experience that behaviour on linux. A friend of mine also uses both applications and never reported that kind of issue to me.

This is so strange to me and I can't figure out the reason for it. From what I get this can't really be code related because it happens in two totally different applications and from what I can tell only since I reinstalled Windows.

EDIT 1: Now I found something interesting, I added the following code on windows and linux:

```
selectSize = select(mysocket + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &timeout);
std::cout << selectSize << std::cout;
```

Interesting thing is that on Windows my console will now output: `Trying to connect...0.1.0.1.0.1.0.1`

Restarted the application and it outputs `Trying to connect...0.0.0.0.0.1`

On linux it always returns `Trying to connect...0.0.0.0.0`, never ever with a false positive.

Still only happening on windows. Don't even know what approach the guy from the C# application used but there it's the same problem happening randomly after reinstalling windows.

EDIT 2: I guess I found the problem.

Before the timeout settings and select() I'm doing a sendto() with my login packet. I guess for whatever reason there is something incoming in return, so that selectSize might change to 1 in some cases. Is it possible that this is causing the issue on Windows, while its working on linux?

Comment: At first glance it sounds as if `select` is returning immediately having encountered an error.  You really should be checking for that.

Comment: Hi, I added some more output to my initial question.

Comment: Maybe the windows firewall? Have you tried using wireshark to look at the exchanged data and also to see who drops the connection or fails to respond?

Comment: The windows firewall is disabled at the moment. This is a "connectionless" UDP socket, so there is not real connection dropping. But in fact the gameserver can't respond when offline, so select() should always return 0 as there is simply nothing coming from the server. Instead it randomly returns 1's, then again 0's. Under linux this works flawless. Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it seems that I finally found at least a partial answer to my initial question, why linux gives me a working result while windows breaks my application. From what I have read on windows platforms select() returns WSAECONNECTRESET instead of blocking or timeout, see: [WinSock Recvfrom() now returns WSAECONNRESET instead of blocking or timing out](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/263823)

So this seems to be the reason why the application is working perfectly fine (for my purposes) on linux, where select() still seems to return a timeout while Windows returns that error and breaks my application to a certain extent.

**Solution:**
So I finally found a fix. Special thanks to the guy who reminded me to use Wireshark. At first I tought the select() giving back 1 when it should be 0 after sending the login packet to gameserver while it's offline is totally random but in fact I found out that from time to time I get a "ICMP port unreachable", this caused select() to return 1 instead of 0 (see the link above) Obviously I only want select() to return 1 when an actual login reponse is coming from the sever. On linux this works out of the box and doesn't cause any problems.
For Windows I found a simple fix by adding this code before the select() function:

```
#define SIO_UDP_CONNRESET _WSAIOW(IOC_VENDOR, 12)
DWORD lpcbBytesReturned = 0;
BOOL lpvInBuffer = FALSE;

WSAIoctl(mysocket, SIO_UDP_CONNRESET, &lpvInBuffer, sizeof(lpvInBuffer), NULL, 0, &lpcbBytesReturned, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from "the" POSIX specification [(a copy of it online)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pselect.html):

> A descriptor shall be considered ready for reading when a call to an input function with O_NONBLOCK clear would not block, whether or not the function would transfer data successfully. (The function might return data, **an end-of-file indication, or an error other than one indicating that it is blocked, and in each of these cases the descriptor shall be considered ready for reading.**)

So I'd say in order to fix your code you must *additionally* check whether file descriptors that are "ready for reading" don't have any error or eof indication.

Comment: I found an error, that the Windows application gives me, when selectSize is 1 where it should be 0, then it also receives the following error code: WSAECONNRESET
10054

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly valid behaviour. That select returning one indicates that there is one socket on which you can call a reading function without having to fear that this function blocks. It does **not** tell you whether that reading would be successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the socket is connected, you should check it for writability, not readability. Change

```
selectSize = select(mysocket + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &timeout);
```

to

```
selectSize = select(mysocket + 1, 0, &fds, 0, &timeout);
```

Comment: Tried this and used it before my first sendto() (<= login packet). Always returns 1 even when the gameserver is offline.